# Ordering a collection by instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to order a collection first by priority and then due time like this:

```
@ods = Od.order(:priority, :due_date_time)
```

The problem is `due_date_time` is an instance method of Od, so I get

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column ods.due_date_time does not exist

I have tried the following, but it seems that by sorting and mapping ids, then finding them again with .where means the sort order is lost.

```
 @ods = Od.where(id: (Od.all.sort {|a,b| a.due_date_time <=> b.due_date_time}.map(&:id))).order(:priority)
```

due_date_time calls a method from a child association:

```
  def due_date_time
    run.cut_off_time
  end
```

run.cut_off_time is defined here:

```
  def cut_off_time
    (leave_date.beginning_of_day + route.cut_off_time_mins_since_midnight * 60)
  end
```

I'm sure there is an easier way. Any help much appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code for `due_date_time`? Maybe it is possible to turn this into a value in a column instead of a method in your model.

Comment: Thanks.  Question updated to include this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` from ActiveRecord similar to `sort` from ruby. So, `Od.all.sort` run iteration after the database query `Od.all`, run a new iteration `map` and then send a new database query. Also `Od.all.sort` has no sense because `where` select record when `id` included in `ids` but not searching a record for each `id`.

Easier do something like this:

```
Od.all.sort_by { |od| [od.priority, od.due_date_time] }
```

But that is a slow solution(`ods` table include 10k+ records). Prefer to save column to sort to the database. When that is not possible set logic to calculate `due_date_time` in a database query.